# Intellij shutdown while making build with maven

Tags: intellij-idea, shutdown

My intelli j is shutdown while making maven build with intelli j.
Below are maven setting in my intelli j.

please let me know if anyone how to solve this issue.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is caused by your antivirus, it kills IntelliJ IDEA process.

Please contact the AV vendor support or your company IT/security helpdesk for the instructions how to exclude IDE and Java processes from the scan/detection.